# Unable to jump all the way to top of page display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hamburger menu icon that toggles a nav list when clicked. The nav list appears at the top of the page. When I am scrolled to the bottom of the page and click the icon I want to jump to the top of the page where the nav is, however, I am unable to jump all the way to the top of my page. I have tried using an anchor tag to jump to a div id at the top as in my example in addition to using both javascript and jquery to jump to the top programmatically. How can I jump all the way to the top where the nav is or else display the nav so it occupies the active part of the screen and can be used?

here is a link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6exhg63d/)

```
<a href="top" class="nav__trigger"><span class="nav__icon"></span></a>
        <div> 
           <nav class="nav" id="nav">
            <ul class="nav__list" style="font-size:2.5em">
              <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#info">Info</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where's the code for the icon for jumping back to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the following from:

```
.nav {
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
          transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
          transition-duration: 300ms;
}
.nav--active .nav {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #000;

}
```

to:

```
.nav {
  z-index: 100;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
          transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
          transition-duration: 300ms;
}
.nav--active .nav {
  display:block;
  background-color: #000;

}
```

by using position absolute and display none then enabling the display when active for a simple solution which will work anywhere on the page without scrolling the user back to. link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6exhg63d/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this script. Put it in the click event of your element

```
$('#element').click(function(){    
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#app_usage_title').offset().top }, 'slow');
});
```